# How to store a return value of an SQL query inside a variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbmigrate

Given a users and a roles table, I want to write an SQL statement, which inserts a new row into the users table and associates a row of the roles table with it.

This is what I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname) VALUES ('John', 'Smith') RETURNING id;

INSERT INTO roles(role, user_id)
VALUES ('ROLE_USER', id);
```

The id used in the last line is not yet associated with the return value of the first line. Can someone explain to me how I could store the return type of the first line inside a variable and then use it in my last line?

I have come across the DECLARE keyword, but I am not sure this works with every kind of database. I am using a postgres DB. When using DECLARE @VariableName, the @ gets marked as wrong syntax in my db-migrate script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_user as (
  INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname) 
  VALUES ('John', 'Smith') 
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO roles(role, user_id)
SELECT 'ROLE_USER', id
FROM new_user;
```

Comment: this works beautifully, thx so much!
... I am not sure I understand it completely, though: What does the WITH statement return? I believe new_user should be an id, but this doesn't seem to be correct as the following SQL fails:
`with new_user_id as (
  INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname) 
  VALUES ('John', 'Smith') 
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO roles(role, new_user_id); `

Comment: The CTE returns the generated ID. But you can't access it "out of thin air". You have to use a SELECT to access the column (and row) from the CTE.